# Redis streams limitations

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis streams. I wonder if there are some restrictions about how many streams can be created and kept alive. 
Let's say I'll need to create and maintain 200k streams.

Documentation does not say (or I missed it) about performance and limitations.

Maybe someone knows articles or has some experience about streams performance related to number of streams and hardware?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only two "restrictions" with regards to any data structure in Redis, Stream included:

1. The data is ultimately capped by the amount of RAM you've provisioned for your database.
2. The maximum number of keys in the database is 2^32.

I don't foresee problems by having Redis manage 200K Streams.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know

Comment: for classical key-value usage of redis, it will write the values to disk and keep only the keys in memory if memory is low. Is the same true for streams?

Comment: @OlliD-Metz "for classical key-value usage of redis, it will write the values to disk and keep only the keys in memory if memory is low" is simply not true.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I guess I was mislead https://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory and thinking such a strategy has been implemented into its core meanwhile. But I do fundamentally not understand how any larger application can use redis, as nobody has infinite RAM???

Comment: Read the note at the beginning of that page - that has been deprecated since 2.4. Infinite RAM is only needed if you have infinite data - nobody has that. Redis can be clustered for horizontal scaling - see https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial